# what are the synonyms for "immediate results"? can I say "soon-achieving results"

Tags: synonyms

The topic of my issue is : Researchers should not limit their investigations to only those areas in which they expect to discover something that has an **immediate**, practical application.

I want to avoid repeating "immediate application" in my issue.I was thinking that maybe "soon-achieving results" is a correct synonyms.(?) are they any better synonyms?

Comment: Each word choice subtly suggests a different meaning. *Application* is not the same as *result*. *Soon-achieving results* is definitely not the same thing as *immediate applications*. Perhaps consider, *they expect to discover things that will have immediate practical applications*.

Answer (score 4):

Some possible phrases using different modifiers for "results":
1. fast results 
2. instant results
3. quick results

Note that "results" is not a precise replacement for "application." Results refer to outcome; application is what might be done with that outcome--the use to which they are put. We can have results from an experiment which have no obvious application. You may want to refer to results which can be quickly applied, to projects resulting in a quick, obvious use, or to the problem with limiting exploration to projects with a practical and predictable purpose.

Answer (score 1):

In any case, it would have to be "soon-achiev*ed*" not "soon-achiev*ing*.  They are results that *we* achieve soon rather than results that achieve {something} soon.

The -ing form of the participial adjective indicates that the noun modified is the actor. The -ed form of the participial adjective indicates that the noun modified is acted upon (or the "patient" -- in the passive role).

We achieved the results quickly.  (Subject -> transitive verb -> object).

The results were achieved quickly by us.

The results were quickly achiev*ing* by us.  [ungrammatical]

Researchers are misguided when they desire quickly achieved results.

Researchers are misguided when they desire quickly achiev*ing* results. [ungrammatical]

Comment: I would use "soon to be achieved results", not "soon achieved results".

Comment: *soon-achieved* is acceptable (like "soon forgotten") but there are better ways to say what the OP wants to say than with a single adjective.